# Looping through afterDraw in ChartJS

Tags: typescript, chart.js, aurelia

I am using afterDraw in an app and there is a ton of dataset data. This code seems to run so many times, over and over again when I only really need it once.

In afterDraw:

```
    for(var i = 0; i < categories; i++)
    {
        let next = start + runningTotal;
        ctx.fillText(chart.config.data.categories[i], next / 2, yBottom + 40);

        start = runningTotal;
        runningTotal = runningTotal + xSpace;
    }
```

It draws over and over. If a put a console in the loop it runs a ton.

The chart looks something like so:

[image]

I want to just run it once at the end.

Comment: Just curious, what happens if you add a `break;` after this line - `runningTotal = runningTotal + xSpace;`?

Comment: What's the value of `categories` in the condition of your `for`-loop? When you're facing so many repetitions it must be cause by a huge amount of loops.

Comment: The value is 3 for categories.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using the `afterDraw` hook, you could use the `afterLayout` or `afterUpdate` hook to execute your custom code.

> Please take a look at chapter [Chart Update](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html#chart-update) from the Chart.js documentation.